# How to Broadcast Messages Between Services?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I've a main activity and couple of activities which are initiated from the main in a sort of user controllable way. Anyway, some of these activities are bounded to their own service. These services, when started, will work until the main activity destroys. I want to know how can I transfer messages between them without combine them all in a service or bind them to every single activity there? I mean, a global message sending instead of LocalBroadcast.

Comment: (1) Are those Services an IntentService with their own Thread or just share the MainThread? (2) Are your Services blocking in their respective Threads?

The right solution depends of what you will answer to those questions.

Comment: They are just services not IntentService. The architecture is in this way that the main activity binds to all available services (but does not start them) just to maintain them during the app is run and by close it will close all the services. each activity will start its own service. you come out of and activity and go to the other while its service is on. But I want to send data from the current activity's service to the other services. Just main activity will stop services not the child activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that your Services are not IntentServices so they use the same MainThread to execute their code.
There could be many different ways to achieve what you want:

1. save Service instances in variables in the MainActivity: Service1 can safety call "MainActivity.mService1instance.doJob()" and Service2 can safety call "MainActivity.mService2instance.doJob()" or do the same result by creating STATIC methods in each Service and call them directly from Service class: "Service2.doJob()"
2. using Handlers: each Service creates its Handler in this way:`mHandler = new Handler() {
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message message) {
           switch (message.what) {
              case TH_MESSAGE_JOBx:
                 break;
           }
       }
   };
   public static boolean postToService(int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj) {
       if (mHandler == null) return false;
       Message cMessage = Message.obtain(mHandler, what, arg1, arg2, obj);
       return mHandler.sendMessage(cMessage);
   }`

   then from ALL THREADS you can safety call the "postToService(TH_MESSAGE_JOBx, int, int, object)" method of each Service

These are the two easies way.

Other ways (but more complicated) could be: AIDL (IPC) and Queues.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.